# I am new to Python. I am facing following error: NameError: name 'ObjFile' is not defined

Tags: python, kivy, nameerror, objloader

```
from objloader import ObjFile


class Renderer(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.canvas = RenderContext(compute_normal_mat=True)
        self.canvas.shader.source = resource_find('simple.glsl')
        self.scene = ObjFile(resource_find("monkey.obj"))
        super(Renderer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            self.cb = Callback(self.setup_gl_context)
            PushMatrix()
            self.setup_scene()
            PopMatrix()
            self.cb = Callback(self.reset_gl_context)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_glsl, 1 / 60.)

    def setup_gl_context(self, *args):
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def reset_gl_context(self, *args):
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

    def update_glsl(self, delta):
        asp = self.width / float(self.height)
        proj = Matrix().view_clip(-asp, asp, -1, 1, 1, 100, 1)
        self.canvas['projection_mat'] = proj
        self.canvas['diffuse_light'] = (1.0, 1.0, 0.8)
        self.canvas['ambient_light'] = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
        self.rot.angle += delta * 100

    def setup_scene(self):
        Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
        PushMatrix()
        Translate(0, 0, -3)
        self.rot = Rotate(1, 0, 1, 0)
        m = list(self.scene.objects.values())[0]
        UpdateNormalMatrix()
        self.mesh = Mesh(
            vertices=m.vertices,
            indices=m.indices,
            fmt=m.vertex_format,
            mode='triangles',
        )
        PopMatrix()


class RendererApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Renderer()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    RendererApp().run()
```

Comment: Do you have a file named `objloader.py`? If so, what is in it?

Comment: No. I don't have objloader.py

Answer (score 1):

Your code is copied from the kivy `3dRendereing` example, but you haven't copied the entire example. That code requires the `objloader.py` file (as well as `monkey.obj` and `simple.glsl`). Copy all those files into the same folder, then the code should work.